# How to open windows in my app with redirect to another app download page in google play

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

There are apps that open a windows that show another app page on Google play, and you can download it from there.
Like this:
[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a web link in your app like below:

"http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>"

This should open your app in Google Play. Or if the user have no Google Play on his device it will open the link with the default browser.